# How find last day of previous month on the basis of Month and year in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a requirement where I have to find the closing balance of previous month 
on the basis of month and year.

I have tried this code:

```
DECLARE @month NUMERIC = 11
DECLARE @Year NUMERIC = 2017

SELECT  
    DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, @Month, DATEADD(YEAR, @Year - 1900, 0)))
```

but this is returning the value of last day of the current month `'2017-11-30 00:00:00.000'`.

Instead of this I want the last day of the previous month: `'2017-10-31 00:00:00.000'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going right just add `-1` to your variable `@Month` for last month date:

```
SELECT  Dateadd(day, -1, Dateadd(month, @Month-1, 
                                      Dateadd(year, @Year - 1900, 0) 
                                             ))
```

Result :

```
2017-10-31 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can simplify a bit by only using 2 DATEADD()

```
SELECT  DATEADD(month, @Month - 1, DATEADD(year, @Year - 1900, -1))
```

or convert the @Year to months and only use single DATEADD()

```
SELECT  DATEADD(month, (@Year - 1900) * 12 + @Month - 1, - 1)
```